# Defining static constexpr values in an enum like wrapper class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, c++14, constexpr

I have a class that I regularly use for an enum wrapper, however this requires a cpp file.  Can anyone show me how to use constexpr

The header file is as follows:

```
// Extend-able in the future
class CDUVariable {
public:
    enum Value {
        baud, firmware, type, serial
    };
    static const CDUVariable Baud, Firmware, Type, Serial;

    /// Comparison operator (used for strict weak ordering).
    bool operator<(const CDUVariable& rhs) const {
        return mValue < rhs.mValue;
    }

    /// Integral operator cast for switch statements (cast to named enum).
    operator const Value() const {
        return mValue;
    }

    /// Serialized version of the enum.
    std::string getStringVal() const {
        return mStringVal;
    }
    static const std::set<CDUVariable>& getValues() {
        static std::set<CDUVariable> gValues;
        if (gValues.empty()) {
            gValues.insert(Baud);
            gValues.insert(Firmware);
            gValues.insert(Type);
            gValues.insert(Serial);
        }
        return gValues;
    }
    static CDUVariable valueOf(const std::string& rStringVal) {
        for (const auto& next : getValues()) {
            if (next.getStringVal() == rStringVal) {
                return next;
            }
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "Illegal Argument: " + rStringVal);
    }
private:
    CDUVariable(const Value& rValue, const std::string& rStringVal)
        : mValue(rValue)
        , mStringVal(rStringVal)
    {}
    Value mValue;
    std::string mStringVal;
};
```

and the cpp file is:

```
const CDUVariable CDUVariable::Baud(baud, "0");
const CDUVariable CDUVariable::Firmware(firmware, "1");
const CDUVariable CDUVariable::Type(type, "2");
const CDUVariable CDUVariable::Serial(serial, "3");
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use the new constexpr syntax to initialize everything in the header file.  I am having trouble with the syntax.

I tried prefixing modifying the header as follows:

```
// Extend-able in the future
class CDUVariable {
public:
    constexpr enum Value {
        baud, firmware, type, serial
    };
    constexpr static CDUVariable Baud(baud, "0") Firmware(firmware, "1"), Type(type, "2"), Serial(serial, "3");
```

But this ended up giving me a bunch of errors.  I would like to know how to migrate to the new constexpr syntax and the plus side of this would be that I could ship a header only library containing these enum type classes.

```
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(107): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'baud'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(107): error C3646: 'Firmware': unknown override specifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(107): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(107): error C2059: syntax error: '('
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(147): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(147): error C2098: unexpected token after data member 'mValue'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(147): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(111): error C2065: 'mValue': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(111): error C2039: 'mValue': is not a member of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(102): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(116): error C2065: 'mValue': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(126): error C3867: 'CDUVariable::Baud': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(127): error C2065: 'Firmware': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(128): error C2065: 'Type': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(129): error C2065: 'Serial': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(146): error C2614: 'CDUVariable': illegal member initialization: 'mValue' is not a base or member
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(165): error C2350: 'CDUVariable::Baud' is not a static member
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(165): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable::Baud'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(165): error C2248: 'CDUVariable::CDUVariable': cannot access private member declared in class 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(143): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable::CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(102): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(166): error C2039: 'Firmware': is not a member of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(102): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(166): error C2065: 'firmware': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(167): error C2039: 'Type': is not a member of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(102): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(167): error C2065: 'type': undeclared identifier
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(168): error C2039: 'Serial': is not a member of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\include\vcdu\vcduconstants.h(102): note: see declaration of 'CDUVariable'
2>c:\users\johnc\main\app739\src\vcdu\vcduconstants.cpp(168): error C2065: 'serial': undeclared identifier
2>Generating Code...
```

Comment: Do you ever want to copy or assign CDUVariable? What is the typical use case? (I have the suspicion, we may be dealing with a XY problem.)

Comment: @Walter The typical use case it to treat these Enum type classes like their java equivalent.  The idea is that I can do things like 'auto cduVariable = CDUVariable(CDUVariable::valueOf(static_cast<CDUVariable::Value>(data))' where I can look up an enum from raw data.  I can also getStringVal and send a pretty printed version to a log.  I tried changing the std::string to a const char* to work around the non constexpr std::string but I couldn't get a header only version to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a class that I regularly use for an enum wrapper, however this requires a cpp file. Can anyone show me how to use constexpr

To reduce your example to a minimal one, consider the following class:

```
struct Example {
    enum Value { A, B };
    static constexpr Example Foo{Value::A, "bar" };
    constexpr Example( Value v, std::string s): v{v}, s{s} {}

private:
    Value v;
    std::string s;
};
```

This is more or less a reduced version of your last attempt.
Almost all the pieces required to be able to construct a `constexpr` version of `Example` are in place, but for the fact that:

- `static constexpr` data members must be initialized, but `Example` is an incomplete type at the point of declaration of `Foo`.
- All the data members must be (let me say) `constexpr` constructible and `std::string` hasn't a `constexpr` constructor you can use.

Therefore your attempt will fail, no doubts about that.

Moreover, note that you cannot odr-use `constexpr` data members unless you are using C++17 or you define them separately in a `.cpp` file, exactly as you did until now. That's because those members are not implicitly defined in C++11/14.
It means that you cannot even use them with `std::set::insert` for it accepts only references. At least, you cannot use them unless you put a definition in a `.cpp` file, of course.

So, back to the question:

> Can anyone show me how to use constexpr

No, we cannot and it doesn't worth it. It seems to me that you want odr-usable data members, so go on with `static` ones and put definitions in a dedicated file.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an enum values are constant, after all, you can't add values at runtime. That's why one reason you are not allowed to put `constexpr` before an enum declaration, it would make no sense, as it wouldn't change anything about the `enum`:

```
constexpr enum Value { baud, firmware, type, serial };
^^^^^^^^^
 illegal
```

As a side note, you cannot construct a `constexpr` `CDUVariable` right now because its constructor is not `constexpr`. If you try to mark it appropriately, it will fail, because `mStringVal` doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor and every variable has to be initialized.

If you are only going to store single characters, use a `char`, which as a primitive, is able to be constructed at compile time.

Comment: _By definition, an enum is already constexpr_ <- That's not exact, it introduces named constants instead.

Comment: @skypjack Well, yeah, but those named constants are `constexpr` because they are fixed at compile time. Isn't it clear from my sentence? How should I word it instead? Because it's clear to me like it is now., but I'm not a native.

Comment: They are constant more than `constexpr` (in the way the language defines them).

Comment: @skypjack Ah ok. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: You are welcome. See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum) for further details. As you can read _an enumeration is a distinct type with named constants_ and _the identifiers in an enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are required_. `constexpr` isn't even mentioned here, as specified by the language.

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of those static variables with:

```
static const std::set<CDUVariable>& getValues() {
    static const std::set<CDUVariable> gValues = {
        { baud, "0"}, // or Baud(),
        { firmware, "1"},
        { type, "2"},
        { serial, "3"}
    };
    return gValues;
}
```

and

```
static const CDUVariable& Baud() { static const CDUVariable var{ baud, "0"}; return var; }
```

or

```
static CDUVariable Baud() { return { baud, "0"}; }
```